# Passing date parameter in redshift unload query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am using my `UNLOAD` statement through a stored procedure to pull data from Redshift. Here is how my code:

Stored Procedure:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE upload_redshift_to_s3(SQLStatement text, s3_path text, iamrole text)
    LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
    $$
    DECLARE
       delimiter varchar(5);
       unload_query varchar(1000);
    BEGIN
       delimiter:='|';
       unload_query := 'unload ('''||SQLStatement||''') to '''||s3_path||''' iam_role '''||iamrole||''' delimiter '''||delimiter||''' ALLOWOVERWRITE HEADER PARALLEL OFF';
       execute unload_query;
    END
    $$;
```

Here is how I am calling it:

```sql
call upload_redshift_to_s3('select processsourceeventcreatedatepst, me_date, id1_value, id2_value, id3_value, id4_value
from failure_detail where processsourceeventcreatedatepst = ''2019-12-06'' and system_id = 5 and failure_type_id = 5',
's3://test-bucket/failures/2019-12-18/FSP_Missing', 
'arn:aws:iam::xxxx:role/houston-fnt-redshift-role');
```

Problem that I am facing is that the date parameter in the sql query. How can I pass it as date here? It only running the query but not pulling any data.

Comment: With regards to the date... Can you please show a sample value for `processsourceeventcreatedatepst`? I'd be interested to see whether it is a `date` or a `timestamp`.

Comment: no this is a date like '2019-12-06'

Before setting this value into the sql I am doing this in the java code 

private String buildFormattedExtractionDate(LocalDate localDate) {

    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");

    LocalDate extractionDate = localDate.minusDays(1);

    //logger.log("buildFormattedExtractionDate done");

    return extractionDate.format(dateTimeFormatter);

  }

Comment: so the LocalDate is converted to a String when I am building the query

Comment: I suggest you try the query in an SQL client to confirm that it works correctly. Then, as a test, try hard-coding the entire query in the procedure just to confirm that it runs correctly. If it does run, then the problem is related to the construction of the string within the procedure. Try to somehow view the exact contents of `unload_query` to debug what is happening.

Comment: Will try. What's the general format to pass a date into sql in upload? I am actually testing it in the aws console

Comment: sample sql : select * from test where processdate = ''2019-12-06'' and system_id = 5 and failure_type_id = 5

This works for all the conditions except the date

Comment: So, are you saying that you ran that query directly in an SQL Client (_not_ via a stored procedure) and you had problems with the date? If so, it is sounding like the format of the date in the `processdate` is not what you are expecting. If you select a few values from `processdate`, what do they look like?

Answer (score 3):

I presume your problem is related to the quotation marks around the date.

From [UNLOAD - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html):

> If your query contains quotation marks (for example to enclose literal values), put the literal between two sets of single quotation marks—you must also enclose the query between single quotation marks:
>
> `('select * from venue where venuestate=''NV''')`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried to run the follow sql in the upload command.

'select processsourceeventcreatedatepst, me_date, id1_value, id2_value, id3_value, id4_value from failure_detail where processsourceeventcreatedatepst = ' '2019-12-18' ' and system_id = 8 and failure_type_id = 4'

but this gave me 

[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "2019";
any other idea?

Comment: Do NOT put a space between the quotation marks. Use: `= ''2019-12-18''` (they are 2 x single quotes on each side)

Comment: Can you please edit your Question and provide the full contents of the query that is run? (That is, the value of `unload_query`.)

Comment: Updated to exactly what I am running